# Quartz Scheduler Memory Leak in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I use quartz version `2.2.2` and Spring Boot version `1.3.1`. It behaves as it should and all works fine. But the problem arises when i try to shut down this application. Log shows there is a memory leak...

My Quartz Configuration;

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = my-app-jobs
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=2
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true
```

I have 2 Classes which implement job like below;

```
/**
 *
 * To Run Every 15 Minutes
 *
 */
public class MemoryDataUpdateJob implements Job {

    @Autowired
    private Dao dao;

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        Logger.info(getClass().getName(), "Scheduled Memory Data Update Job Started...");

        //Read Device Settings
        dao.readDeviceSettings();

        Logger.info(getClass().getName(), "Scheduled Memory Data Update Job Finished.");
    }

}
```

Other Class is also similar doing different stuff.

Scheduler Factory Bean as follows;

```
@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean(
        JobFactory jobFactory,
        @Qualifier("MemoryDataUpdateJobTrigger") Trigger memoryDataUpdateJobTrigger,
        @Qualifier("MsgCountJobTrigger") Trigger msgCountJobTrigger) throws IOException {
    SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
    factory.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties());
    factory.setTriggers(memoryDataUpdateJobTrigger, msgCountJobTrigger);
    return factory;
}
```

I was getting tomcat log like below;

```
19-Jan-2016 11:18:39.722 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [MyApp-1.0.0] appears to have started a thread named [schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)

19-Jan-2016 11:18:39.722 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [MyApp-1.0.0] appears to have started a thread named [schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
```

Went through quartz documentation and added the following in properties;

```
org.quartz.plugin.shutdownhook.class = org.quartz.plugins.management.ShutdownHookPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.shutdownhook.cleanShutdown = true
```

The First thread message disappeared but second message about `worker-2` memory leak is still there.

But in my Application Logger i see something like this;

```
[2016-01-19 11:18:39:681] [DEBUG] [schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1] [org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool:612] - WorkerThread is shut down.

[2016-01-19 11:18:40:047] [DEBUG] [schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-2] [org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool:612] - WorkerThread is shut down.

[2016-01-19 11:18:40:049] [INFO ] [Quartz Shutdown-Hook schedulerFactoryBean] [org.quartz.plugins.management.ShutdownHookPlugin:126] - Shutting down Quartz...
```

What is the problem here? Why there is a memory leak even if the application logger shows threads are shutdown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it. The problem was tomcat was shutting down but the quartz jobs was running. If we wait for sometime like 1 sec then it shuts down properly. We can do it by extending `SchedulerFactoryBean` and overriding it's `destroy` method. Something like below;

```
public class SchedulerFactoryBeanWithWait extends SchedulerFactoryBean {

@Override
public void destroy() throws SchedulerException {
    super.destroy();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logError(e);
    }
 }
}
```

and the bean declaration;

```
@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBeanWithWait schedulerFactoryBeanWithWait (
        JobFactory jobFactory,
        @Qualifier("MemoryDataUpdateJobTrigger") Trigger memoryDataUpdateJobTrigger,
        @Qualifier("MsgCountJobTrigger") Trigger msgCountJobTrigger) throws IOException {
    SchedulerFactoryBeanWithWait factory = new SchedulerFactoryBeanWithWait ();
    factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
    factory.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties());
    factory.setTriggers(memoryDataUpdateJobTrigger, msgCountJobTrigger);
    return factory;
}
```

This makes it wait till the threads are down. Maybe it will help someone in future.

Answer (score 1):

SchedulerFactoryBean has had a flag to tell it to wait for jobs to complete since at least Spring 3.0. Set the flag and make sure the destroy method will be called at shutdown:

```
@Bean(destroyMethodName="destroy")
public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean(
        JobFactory jobFactory,
        @Qualifier("MemoryDataUpdateJobTrigger") Trigger memoryDataUpdateJobTrigger,
        @Qualifier("MsgCountJobTrigger") Trigger msgCountJobTrigger) throws IOException {
    SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    factory.setWaitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
    factory.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties());
    factory.setTriggers(memoryDataUpdateJobTrigger, msgCountJobTrigger);
    return factory;
}
```

or with XML config:

```
<bean id="scheduler"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean"
        destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
    ....
</bean>
```

See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SchedulerFactoryBean.html#setWaitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown(boolean)